# Running a command with timeout

Tags: rust, command-line

I'm translating a command line program from Python to Rust.

The program has to run different commands that could not terminate.

The Python version uses `subprocess.run()` that accepts `timeout` as argument.

For example:

```
result = subprocess.run(["java", "MyProgram"],
                        timeout=timeout,
                        capture_output=True)
```

When translating into Rust, I'm using:

```
let out = Command::new("java")
    .arg("MyProgram")
    .output()?;
```

But as long as I know, Command is not allowing me to specify any timeout.

Since it will run on GNU/Linux, I could simply wrap the call with `timeout` (as in `timeout 10 java MyProgram`) but I wonder if there's any solution that does not depend on `timeout`.

So the question is: how do I run a command from Rust with a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you could handle this.

One would be to start a background thread and use `Child::kill()` to kill the process after a timeout.  You would need to use `Arc` to share the object between threads.  This is a bit problematic though because the methods of `Child` require a mutable reference to the `Child`, so you can't wait on the process from one thread at the same time as you try to kill it from another.

Another approach would be to use `Child::try_wait()` in a spinloop and kill the process when the wall clock has passed a threshold time.

Alternatively, consider using the `wait_timeout` crate, which wraps up this complexity behind a simple function.

Comment: You can use channels to send to process to the second thread.

Comment: The wait_timeout pointer solved my problem. Thanks! The example in the crate doc was clear enough: https://docs.rs/wait-timeout/0.2.0/wait_timeout/index.html

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, but if you have one thread locked in `Child::wait()` then you can't kill the process no matter what messaging gymnastics you use because both `Child::wait()` and `Child::kill()` require a mutable reference to the child. After thinking about it for a bit, I don't think multiple threads can actually be useful in the solution to this problem using only the API Rust exposes here.

Comment: The usual Unix way of implementing a timeout for a child process is handling SIGCHLD. Signal handling never is fun, but it is the only asynchronous solution I'm aware of.